# Why am I getting a false average when applied on temporary table column

Tags: postgresql, average

I'm trying to get the average of words based on each `message.body` count of words from `messages` table

an example of that would be

```
**message.body**
-------------------
-->"aaz aae aar"
-->"aaz"
-->"aaz aae"
```

Output must be: **AVG( 3 + 1 + 2 ) = 2**

For that I've been applying the following query

```
SELECT AVG(temp.words) FROM (SELECT (array_length(string_to_array(messages.body,' '),1)) AS words FROM messages) AS temp
```

`message.body`  is just text.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question:
it happens that average function in postgres only accepts Floats as an argument, for that someone needs to cast the input before. Like this:

```
SELECT(AVG (temporary_.words)) AS average_amount FROM (SELECT CAST(array_length(string_to_array(messages.body,' '),1)  AS FLOAT) AS words FROM messages WHERE body!='' ) AS temporary_
```

Answer (score 1):

giving the result you expect:

```
t=# with messages(body) as (values('aaz aae aar'),('aaz'),('aaz aae')) SELECT AVG(temp.words) FROM (SELECT (array_length(string_to_array(messages.body,' '),1)) AS words FROM messages) AS temp;
        avg
--------------------
 2.0000000000000000
(1 row)

t=# with messages(body) as (values('aaz aae aar'),('aaz'),('aaz aae')) SELECT *FROM (SELECT (array_length(string_to_array(messages.body,' '),1)) AS words,messages.body FROM messages) AS temp;
 words |    body
-------+-------------
     3 | aaz aae aar
     1 | aaz
     2 | aaz aae
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I'm curious on what's the difference ? I guess data you generated is different from mine message.body